# Django - Custom Model Form used in a template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I've been trying to figure out how to create a custom html template that when submitted will upload to a model form. I'm newer to Django so so far i've been a little confused on the Django Docs on the forms. I have created a custom HTML Template it looks like:

HTML:

```
 <form role="form" method="post" action="." id="js-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %} 
       <img  id="image1" src="/media/{{ gallery.logo }}" alt="">
          <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" multiple>
              <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Register" id="js-upload-submit" >
       </form>
```

You can notice that I have given the input ID = logo. When I click submit I would like this to upload an image to my ModelForm.

Form:

```
class UploadFileForm(ModelForm):

    logo = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ['logo']
```

Models:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name, null=True, blank=True)
```

Is there anyway with the specific way I have designed my HTML template to submit the image to the Model Form? I am trying to avoid using { form.as_p } and such as it doesnt do the customization I would like.

Answer (score 1):

You should send the `form`  object to the template and call the `{{form.logo}}` field.

## View:

```
if request.method == 'POST':  # When the form is submitted
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
         new_content = form.save()
         # After the form.save a new model is created 
         # and the file is uploaded to the desired location
else: 
    form = UploadFileForm()

ctx = {}
ctx['form'] = form

return render_to_response('yourtemplate.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## Template:

```
 <form role="form" method="post" action="." id="js-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %} 
   {{form.logo}} 
 </form>
```

## Customization:

If you would like to customize the input field, you should hide the form field like:

```
 <form role="form" method="post" action="." id="js-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %} 
   {{form.logo.as_hidden}} # This won't show the input
 </form>
```

And now to customize the input you should show your custom input and via jQuery or JavaScript bind the custom input/button to the hidden form logo field.

E.g:

If you want to trigger the file select with a custom button, you should do:

```
# ... Other code
<button class='btn btn-success yourclass' onClick='selectFile'>

<script>
  function selectFile(){
    $('#id_logo').click()
  }
<script>
```

Comment: How do I create my own custom input for form.logo?

Comment: I added the answer now, one easy way is to hide the `{{form.logo}}` input, customize a new input/button and bind the custom input/button to the hidden `{{form.logo}}` input. ( The ID of form.field is allways **id_field** so for form.logo will be **id_logo** )